# Can anyone explain VMware vSphere in layman's terms?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

Can anyone provide a brief explanation in layman's terms (as in "management friendly") of just what vSphere is, what can be done with it and why it's better than the alternatives?

Also, examples of possible real-world applications appreciated.

Comment: Can you name the alternatives that you're faced with?

Comment: I am afraid not, having a hard time finding those too!

Comment: So, since we're technical, can you explain to us why you want vSphere, and we can help you translate? Are you entirely new to VMware? What are you using it for?

Comment: What I'm asking is, are your alternatives either ESX without VSphere, or a different platform for virtualization entirely?

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to sound too negative.
If you are asking this question you shouldn't be deploying this by yourself.  I would recommend hiring some consultants to help you along with the process.

Comment: @PHLiGHT won't be deploying anything anytime soon man, if so I will definitely get professionals to do it ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

vSphere allows you to run multiple virtual machines on a single piece of hardware.  Basically you take a single machine with say 16 CPU cores and 64 Gigs of RAM, and you slice that up into smaller bits so that you can run a bunch of smaller machines on it.  Say 10 different virtual machines with 2 CPUs and 4 Gigs of RAM each.  Some of these virtual machines can run Windows, some Linux, some Unix, etc all on a single piece of hardware saving you money on hardware, power, cooling, rack space, etc.

The biggest competitor to vSphere is Microsoft's Hyper-V.  vSphere is a more mature product which gives it a leg up.  The biggest benefit that vSphere has over Hyper-V are:

- vSphere has a much smaller install footprint that Hyper-V
- vSphere allows you to vMotion (Live Migrate in Hyper-V language) more machines from one host to another at a time (1 for Hyper-V vs. 4 or 8 on vSphere depending on the network config).
- vSphere doesn't require physical Windows domain controllers where Hyper-V requires at least one physical domain controller (it is recommended that the vCenter server is run on a physical server however).
- If you have the vSphere Enterprise Plus edition then you can use the virtual Cisco switch and run a virtual managed switch so that the switch can be managed just like any physical network switch by the networking team.

Now do keep in mind that not every server can be virtualized.  Some servers just aren't good candidates for making them a VM, however that said, in most companies there is no reason that most physical servers couldn't be virtualized.

Comment: To add to the excellent post above: In management terms, it allows you to minimize investments in hardware by more effectively utilizing fewer purchases.

Comment: I may have given a presentation or two on virtualization (both on Hyper-V and vSphere). :)

Comment: @mrdenny thanks man - this is *exactly* what I was looking for

Comment: No problem. If any more questions come up let me know.  I'm happy to answer them.

Comment: one additional query that I would have is how does this fit into cloud computing - does VMWare also provide vSphere as a cloud-based service? If you could edit your original question with this info it would be great, but if you think it's more appropriate I can ask another question

Comment: When you build a VMware (or Hyper-V) environment you are building a private cloud for your company.  They don't offer a public cloud platform.

Comment: @mrdenny - can you show me where Hyper-V requires at least one physical domain controller? I've looked around and cant find anything to support that. (Not being snarky or anything, I'm genuinely curious if I've misled some of my customers.)

Comment: No problem, I should have clarified that if you have a Hyper-V cluster you will need a physical domain controller, otherwise you will have a hell of a time getting things up and running after a power failure.  Without a physical DC the cluster can't start.  If the cluster can't start then the virtual DCs can't be started.  So you need a single physical DC to start up so that the cluster can authenticate and start all the VMs.

Comment: Ah, good times. So really only necessary for clustering, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you are running standalone Hyper-V servers then the services on the host all run under local system so the physical DC isn't needed.

Comment: Since this has just come up to the frontpage, it's worth noting that this answer and comments are quite out of date. Hyper-V has [a configurable number of simultaneous live-migrations](http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=12729), [doesn't require a physical domain controller](https://serverfault.com/q/680559/57144), also supports pluggable/[Cisco virtual switches](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/nexus-1000v-switch-microsoft-hyper-v/index.html), and VMware [does have a cloud service offering](https://cloud.vmware.com/)

Answer (score 6):

MRDenny's answer is extremely misleading as "vSphere allows you to run multiple virtual machines on a single piece of hardware" is a definition for *any* VM technology (QEMU, KVM, Xen, VirtualBox, VMware player/server/...).

vSphere has a small component that allows running VMs (basically equivalent to QEMU or VMware player), but it is almost entirely a set of tools to configure and manage virtual machines and virtual machine instances. This is done via a set of web GUIs connecting to various service daemons.

Its value is not in the ability to run multiple VMs on a single server (again, any VM technology can do that), but in making the creation and maintenance of those VMs easier.

Comment: I'm not sure how my answer is misleading.  I give a quick overview of what virtualization is as requested (yes I site VMware, but the OP obviously knows there is more than one VM platform out there as he is asking about how VMware is different from competing products), then I go into the differences between the two biggest players without going to in depth so that he's got something to present to management as he requested.

Comment: Your answer is misleading because you did not separate the ESX part out. LIke you compare Hyper-V with vSphere, in reality you should compare vSphere with MSVMM from Microsoft, i naddition to the hypervisor.

Comment: As I see it, mrdenny's answer was on the level the asker needed. A technical answer about hypervisor architecture will not be useful to explain the product to management.

Comment: my question was about vSphere, not virtualization in general, so I can see @Walex's point, but at the same time @mrdenny gives a definition that goes beyond a simple explanation of what virtualization is, which I already knew, just wanted to know how this is achieved through vSphere. However it would be interesting to see some mention of ESX and how it fits into the bigger vSphere picture in the answer